# Is the variance of the multivariate folded normal distribution known?

Tags: probability, variance, folded-normal-distribution

The mean and variance of the [folded normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) are known. Consider now the distribution of $(|x_1|, \ldots, |x_n|)$, where $\mathbb{x} \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$. The mean of the multivariate folded normal distribution is easy to obtain. But what about the variance? I could not find references, and the calculation seems complicated. Any suggestion?

Comment: If $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$, does $|x|$ equal $(|x_1|, |x_2|, \ldots, |x_n|)$ or $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$?  If the former, are you asking for the variance of each $|x_i|$ or the covariance matrix of the random vector?

Comment: @DilipSarwate thanks for the question. Clarification added.

Comment: Do you want just the covariance matrix or the actual multivariate distribution?

Comment: Since this question was asked, a paper (http://sankhya.isical.ac.in/search/75b1/13571_2013_64_PrintPDF.pdf ) on the multivariate folded normal came out. It is not clear if this matches your setting.

Answer (score 2):

There is a section entitled 'Bivariate Half-normal distribution in:
*Continuous Multivariate Distributions: Models and applications*
By Samuel Kotz, Norman Lloyd Johnson, N. Balakrishnan.

I would be curious to see how this can be generalized to a random vector of any dimensions.

In fact, the bivariate case appears to be thoroughly treated in this paper:
http://www.stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jpan/papers/Panaretos-ApplStatScience2001(119-136)ft.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by folded normal distribution.  The distribution of $|X|$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$? The distribution of $|X|$ when $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?  But, regardless of the interpretation, if you aver that *"The mean and variance of the folded normal 
distribution are known"* to you, then rest assured that if $x \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ has a multivariate normal distribution, then $x_i \sim N(\mu_i, \Sigma_{i,i})$ and so whatever formulas are known to you as the mean and variance of $|X|$ where $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$
also can be used for the mean and variance of $|x_i|$ which has a folded normal distribution since $x_i \sim N(\mu_i, \Sigma_{i,i})$.

- If you know only the mean and variance of $|X|$ when $X \sim N(0,1)$ but not when 
  $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then please edit your question to say so clearly.
- If you know formulas for the mean and variance of $|X|$ where 
  $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, please apply the formulas to each $|x_i|$ since
  $x_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_{i,i})$.  It would probably help the readers of
  this forum of you were to type in the formulas for the mean and variance
  of $|X|$.
- If you want to know the covariance of $|x_i|$ and $|x_j|$, please edit
  your question to say so clearly.  You have been asked the same question by
  cardinal also.

Comment: The formulas for the univariate folded normal are known. The same formulas can be applied for the variance of $|x_i|$, since $x_i$ is normal. I am stuck at computing $E|x_i x_j|$.